# How to get marginLeft from an element with absolute position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add an information box over something when you hover over it with your mouse, but I need to get the element's left margin since it moves, but it doesn't have a margin-left property in CSS, and it's position is relative so I don't really need to add a margin-left property. I tried doing `element1.style.marginLeft = element2.style.marginLeft` but it always returns 0

Comment: Please include a complete testable example.

Comment: Just found an error: it should say relative not absolute in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was instead of having them be to seperated in a way, all I did was just set both elements inside of a `<div>` element and it ended up working!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which uses only `CSS` to show a popover info box. It uses `transform` to move the box around instead of `margin`. The reason is that animating with `transform` is more performant than `margin` and the animation will appear much smoother on all devices. The following example also uses some `WAI-ARIA` attributes to make it more accessible for screen reader users.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

[role=dialog] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% + 45px));
  transition: 0.3s transform, 0.3s opacity;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 70%;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.myInfo:hover+[role=dialog],
.myInfo:focus+[role=dialog] {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-50% + 40px));
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 1em;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

p img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="myInfo" aria-describedby="infoDialog">I have more information <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1828/1828885.svg" alt="Info icon" width="16" height="16" role="presentation"></p>
  <div id="infoDialog" role="dialog">
    More information found here
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn5mh7at/35/)

Comment: This could be very interesting to work with, but I'm not trying to animate the info box. I'm simply trying to place the info box at the same exact Vector2 position as the element it gives more information on

Comment: @DatMADScripter Can you include a picture of what you want?

Comment: here's the image raw.githubusercontent.com/DatMADCoder/images/… I want to have the info thing over the box beside the one with the info, without setting the margin-left maunally